# delay/sleep in Swift is not working

Tags: ios, swift, delay, wait, sleep

I have a problem with the `sleep` function in Swift code. I'm using `import Darwin` and `usleep(400000)`. Some actions before reaching the sleep are blocked and I dont know why. Here a short example from my code:

```
@IBAction func Antwort4Button(_ sender: Any) {
    if (richtigeAntwort == "4"){
        Antwort4.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        Ende.text = "Richtig!"

        NaechsteFrage()
    }
    else {
        Ende.text = "Falsch!"

        //NaechsteFrage()
    }
}

func NaechsteFrage() {
    usleep(400000)

    Antwort1.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    Antwort2.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    Antwort3.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    Antwort4.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

    Ende.text = ""

    FragenSammlung()
}
```

This lines will be not executed:

```
Antwort4.backgroundColor = UIColor.green

Ende.text = "Richtig!"
```

Why is calling sleep blocking these actions? If I delete the `import Darwin` and the `sleep`, my code works fine. Has anyone an idea? Sorry for my bad english :P

Comment: Don't use `sleep` or variants. You're blocking the main thread doing nothing.  Use [`dispatch_after`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/dispatch/1452876-dispatch_after)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Others alrady answered the question, I just wanted to provide some additional information (cannot comment yet).

You said that `Antwort4.backgroundColor = UIColor.green` is not executed. To clarify, this is executed, but you don't see the result becuase you call `sleep`, which is blocking the UI. Here is what happens:

1. set background color of `Antwort4` to green
2. sleep: block the UI which prevents the app from actually showing the green background
3. set the background color of `Antwort4` to red again

To solve the problem at hand you can use Apples [Displatch](https://developer.apple.com/reference/dispatch) API. So instead of sleept, you could use:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
    self.Antwort1.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    self.Antwort2.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    self.Antwort3.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    self.Antwort4.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

    self.Ende.text = ""

    self.FragenSammlung()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

like @jcaron said

here the code to do it:

```
func delay(delayTime: Double, completionHandler handler:@escaping () -> ()) {
        let newDelay = DispatchTime.now() + delayTime
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: newDelay, execute: handler)
    }
```

Edited: you can create a viewController extension to use in any viewControllers like this:

```
extension UIViewController {

    func delay(delayTime: Double, completionHandler handler:@escaping () -> ()) {
            let newDelay = DispatchTime.now() + delayTime
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: newDelay, execute: handler)
        }
}
```

So in your viewController you just call like this:

```
delay(delayTime: 2, completionHandler: {
            _ in
            // do your code here
        })
```

Comment: thank you very much, but there is one thing i dont know :P what i have to use as second parameter in delay(2, ?)

Comment: The second parameter is the closure, you use that to return the function for the one who call it after the delay is finish. You return in here execute: handler). I've changed the code so you can use in any viewControllers without creating the function again.

Answer (score 1):

The [`usleep()`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/usleep.3.html) function will block your UI. If you don't want to have this behavior better use the [`Timer`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/timer) class.